# INSERT INTO query returning "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried looking everywhere within the site and within Microsoft documentation, but I am stuck at running a query to insert objects into my table. What am I doing wrong to get the

> "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'cate'"

error?

Here is the query:

```
INSERT INTO t_lu_Product ([product_id], [description], [isCompetition], [category], 
                          [subCategory], [brand], [type], [returnability], [capacity]) 
VALUES(200011073, '1.25L PNR CC', 1, 'Cola',
       'Cola Regular', 'Coca-Cola', 'Familiares', 'No Retornable', 1);
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the *exact* query that causes the error?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is this the only thing that you are executing?  Could the error come from code before or after this query?

Comment: Yes, I am running this query straight from a command line console database browser that interacts with the database. This is a stand-alone query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing one of the strings you're trying to insert has an apostrophe in it.  Depending on how you're creating the query you can use parameters or escape the apostrophe:

```
INSERT INTO t_lu_Product ( ... ) VALUES(... ,'Mother''s Cookies',1);
```