# dapper query - fix for "Unclosed quotation mark near ..." error

Tags: c#, dapper

This query works; that is, it returns the expected results:

```
var r = sql.Query<T>("select * from TableName where Name = '" + name + "'");
```

but, if one of the 'names' values contains an apostrophy (which is true), then an exception is thrown '{"Incorrect syntax near 'Resources'.\r\nUnclosed quotation mark after the character string ''."}' - in an attempt to [fix that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17412205/3259125), my query no longer returns any results; but it should.

I've attempted to change the code in a few ways, but no results are returned with either of the following changes:

```
var r = sql.Query<T>("select * from TableName where Name = '@name'", new { name });
```

or

```
var args = new DynamicParameters(name);
var r = sql.Query<T>("select * from TableName where Name = '@name'", args);
```

or

```
var args = new DynamicParameters(); args.AddDynamicParams(new { name });
var r = sql.Query<T>("select * from TableName where Name = '@name'", args);
```

or

```
var args = new DynamicParameters(); args.Add("@name", name);
var r = sql.Query<T>("select * from TableName where Name = '@name'", args);
```

This is probably something trivial that I have simply just not yet grasped the concept for ... but I'm at the point of having spent too much time trying to figure it out - hence the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a parameter is the right way to go. You absolutely *don't* want to put the value into the query itself as you did in your first snippet. However, you've put the `@name` in quotes, which means it's being treated as a string literal... it's looking for a name value of exactly `@name` rather than the value of the `@name` parameter. You want:

```
var r = sql.Query<T>("select * from TableName where Name = @name", new { name });
```

(That's probably the simplest way of passing the parameters, though the other approaches should work too.)

Now I haven't actually *used* Dapper myself, but that's what I'd expect...

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing after reading your initial posted answer!  I knew it had to be something trivial - I didn't realize that putting the `@name` in single quotes forced it to be treated as a string literal.  Thanks.

Comment: It pleases me when what a non-user of a library would *expect* is indeed exactly how the API works. It suggests we got it right.